# get_posts filter meta_query using ACF Checkbox

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, get-posts

I have a checkbox field for a `custom_post_type` called `distributors`.

[image]

I am using get_posts and meta_query to filter the posts by the `region` checked. Each post has a value of `canada` or `usa`.

In my code I get their session which defines `$country` as `canada` or `usa` and is used in the `meta_value` field of arguments.

Here is my code:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'     => 'distributors',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'meta_query'    =>  array (
        'key'     => 'region',
        'value'   => $country,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
);
$distributors = get_posts($args);
```

It should then only show posts `distributors` which has a region matching the visitor's session.

**In the above case it outputs all `distributor` posts.**

I did a `var_dump` to find out why it's not matching. In the case of a `usa` related post, it shows the `region` stored as:

```
["ID"]=>
int(13353)
["city"]=>
string(9) "Elizabeth"
["province"]=>
string(10) "New Jersey"
["region"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "usa"
}
```

In this case, in the database the value looks like:

[image: database value for usa]

In the case of a `canada` related post it shows `region` as:

```
["ID"]=>
int(12840)
["city"]=>
string(7) "Concord"
["province"]=>
string(7) "Ontario"
["region"]=>
string(6) "canada"
```

In the database, the value looks like so:

[image: database canada value]

**What can I do to match when some values are NOT serialized and other are?** I have a feeling some post data was imported directly and others were added via the wordpress dashboard which might account for some values not being serialized while others are.

Comment: Region would work much much better as a taxonomy.

Comment: That's a really good point, thanks! I may invest the time in changing that across the theme files.